# how to call simple addition function in c file from javascript through native client

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

```
I have installed **naclsdk** with stable pepper35 version.
```

i found getting started tutorial for c++ but i cant find any **simple tutorial for c**.As i new to chrome-native client it will be helpful if any one tells **how to call simple c function from javascript** through chrome browser because i need to call already existing c algorithm functions from javascript and i need to update graph using that returned value.i tried some examples but i cant understand.. i need to call in javascript like            var ans = pexe_instance.Addition(5,6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Native Client SDK has a few examples that are written in C. Take a look at:

- [examples/demo/nacl_io_demo.c](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/native_client_sdk/src/examples/demo/nacl_io_demo/nacl_io_demo.c)
- [examples/demo/life.c](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/native_client_sdk/src/examples/demo/life/life.c)
- [tutorial/debugging/debugging.c](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/native_client_sdk/src/examples/tutorial/debugging/debugging.c)
- [tutorial/using_ppapi_simple/hello_world.c](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/native_client_sdk/src/examples/tutorial/using_ppapi_simple/hello_world.c).

Passing messages back and forth between Native Client and JavaScript is easiest with ppapi_simple. The life.c example shows how to handle messages in the ProcessEvent function:

```
void ProcessEvent(PSEvent* event) {
  switch(event->type) {
    case PSE_INSTANCE_HANDLEMESSAGE: {
      struct PP_Var var = event->as_var;
      ...
      break;
    }

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```